# What is the **openSUSE way** for using VLAN 10 for my host and VLAN 20 for guest VMs with a bridged connection and KVM?

Tags: opensuse, kvm, bridge, vlan

I have a fresh install of openSUSE Tumbleweed installed on my `box`. During the install process I said to install `KVM Hypervisor` and it defauled to a bridged connection (which is what I want).

My `box` is connected to a port on my switch that allows `VLAN 10` and `VLAN 20` with `VLAN 20` being the default. I cannot change the settings of my switch/firewall/network.

Now I am trying to figure out the **openSUSE way to**:

1. Configure the host to be `VLAN 10`
2. Configure a VM to be `VLAN 20`

I'm going through all the screens in the settings but I cannot find anything.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]